# CMIS QL get folder path using CONTAIN (ALL:)

Tags: alfresco, opencmis, cmis-workbench

I am having a problem retrieving the path of a folder which contains '(' and ')' when I do a query in CMIS.

how can i get the below working ?

```
SELECT cmis:path FROM cmis:folder WHERE IN_TREE('a53471aa-b447-4fdd-a451-4a2beb494226') AND CONTAINS('ALL:Tom_(Robot)')
```

So `(Robot)` that's causing not to find the path.

Any idea how I can make `(` and `)` as part of my query?

Comment: Did you try escaping the brackets?

Comment: yes, but no luck. though this SELECT cmis:path FROM cmis:folder WHERE IN_TREE('a53471aa-b447-4fdd-a451-4a2beb494226') AND CONTAINS('ALL:Tom_Robot') works without brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this problem is

```
SELECT cmis:path FROM cmis:folder WHERE IN_TREE('a53471aa-b447-4fdd-a451-4a2beb494226') AND CONTAINS('ALL:Tom_Robot')
```

By removing the brackets it returns me folder path, somehow it gives me the correct result, but I am still interested on other peoples opinion on this, this does not sound good to me, whether this is openCMIS issue or an Alfresco.